# How to find target sim for an incoming call in dual sim android phone?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, telephonymanager, dual-sim

I am creating an android application in which I need to detect the target sim for an incoming call in dual sim phone. The Android API provides the access of only one SIM. I did googling about this but couldn't find the solution, All I found is that we can not detect the target SIM because this is depend upon the device manufactures.

Is there any API available to detect the target SIM ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35556152/3138818

Answer (score -2):

in lollipop 22+

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
  int slot = Integer.parseInt((String) intent.getExtras().get("slot"));
  if(slot == 0){
    // sim1
  }
  if(slot == 1){
    // sim2
  }
}
```

}

tested in Lenovo K3 note

Comment: There is no slot in the extras.