# How to know SimSlot Number for every Call / sms?

Tags: android, dual-sim

You know the sim slot number only in broadcast receiver. After one month of research I got one solution which is work fine for me as below

**Firstly Add the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission to your manifest file**

***Implement receiver for the phone event which receive call/sms events for your application***

```
public class CallSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      Log.d("SIM_SLOT"," Slot Number "+capturedSimSlot(extras));
    }
  }

/*below methods captures the sim slot number from bundle */

public int capturedSimSlot(Bundle bundle){

        int whichSIM =-1;
        if (bundle.containsKey("subscription")) {
            whichSIM = bundle.getInt("subscription");
        }
        if(whichSIM >=0 && whichSIM < 5){
            /*In some device Subscription id is return as subscriber id*/
            sim = ""+whichSIM;
        }else{
            if (bundle.containsKey("simId")) {
                whichSIM = bundle.getInt("simId");
            }else if (bundle.containsKey("com.android.phone.extra.slot")) {
                whichSIM = bundle.getInt("com.android.phone.extra.slot");
            }else{
                String keyName = "";
                for(String key : bundle.keySet()){
                    if(key.contains("sim"))
                        keyName =key;
                }
                if (bundle.containsKey(keyName)) {
                    whichSIM = bundle.getInt(keyName);
                }
            }
        }
        return whichSIM;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without receiver ? can we get sim id from CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID)?

Comment: yes, but before you need to know the KeyName for slot Number

Comment: KeyName you mean "sim_id" or "subscription_id" ?

Comment: Yes, But its not same for all devices

Comment: So what is the other preferable solution according to you? My requirement is i don't want to use  receiver or bundle.

Comment: firstly, you read all column names from ContentResolver and find simID or similar column name if not find subscription_id and save in your database or SharedPref.

Comment: Later you will use this column name for retrieving sim slot

Comment: firstly, you need to read all column names from ContentResolver and try to find simId, sub_id, or similer keys, if Not found then check subscription_id

Comment: list of possible keys are
simID
sim_id
sub_id
subid
subscription_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99193/discussion-between-user3131373-and-naimish-b-makwana).

Comment: You also get sim slot number or subscription by using ContentResolver, but you need to know the column name..

Answer (score 0):

for sms in lollipop 22+

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
  int slot = Integer.parseInt((String) intent.getExtras().get("slot"));
  if(slot == 0){
    // sim1
  }
  if(slot == 1){
    // sim2
  }
 }
}
```

tested in Lenovo K3 note

Comment: You test on only one device, but Its not work for All. Samsung Devices key is different. I test on multiple Manufacturer You need to check "Key" exists is bundal i.e. slot,simId,subscriptionid etc

Comment: @user3131373, i think from lollipop MR1 all device most have same property for that

Comment: You need to captures slot number only for L+ or whole versions? My Code works for android version above 3.6 [I tested so many devices]