# Android: Target SIM/Number of incoming call

Tags: java, android, android-phone-call

INB4: [How to find target sim for an incoming call in dual sim android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017254/how-to-find-target-sim-for-an-incoming-call-in-dual-sim-android-phone) <- does not work, sadly :(

So, I have a phone (A) with to SIM cards:

> SIM 1 number: 123

> SIM 2 number: 456

and I call from different phone (B: number 789) to 123.
On phone A I'm able to detect incoming call and I'm able to get the incoming phone call number (789). What I can't do is detect that the call target was SIM 1 number: 123.

Can someone help me?

Comment: how you managed to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally manage to do this, but not directly.
I'm getting all information I need from call history.

Comment: this circumvent did the trick (temporary).